# Syntax of a return statement in Java

Tags: java, syntax, return-value

This is in one of my practice exams.

```
return search(p,key,0,p.length-1) !=null;
```

How would this look with if statements?

Comment: This is why CS departments suck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (search(p,key,0,p.length-1) !=null) { 

   return true;

}

return false;
```

Comment: That is only one if statement. The problem clearly called for "if statements". But like you, I am at a loss trying to figure out how to add any more...

Comment: But this is a wrapper method that calls the search method. Why would it return true only if its not null? Shouldnt it return true if its not null AND search returned true?

Comment: @fprime - it is clear that the search method returns an object not a `boolean`, and it is reasonable to assume that it is returning the object found or `null`, where `null` means "no object found".  But in fact, that's not really relevant.  The question can be answered without knowing what the search method's result means.

Comment: @fprime, sorry I was afk.  Stephen said it all.

Answer (score 2):

the only other answer, which is arguably more legible and better if you need to step through the code to debug would be to assign the result of the method to a variable:

```
Object result = search(p, key, 0, p.length - 1);
return result != null;
```

... with 'if statement':

```
Object result = search(p, key, 0, p.length - 1);

if (result == null)
    return false;
else
    return true;
```

... with 'if statements' (not recommended):

```
Object result = search(p, key, 0, p.length - 1);

if (result == null)
    return false;

if (result != null)
    return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

For school assignments, I'd suggest you do something like

```
...
public boolean func(String p, String key)
{
    boolean bOut = false;

    ...

    if (search(p, key, 0, p.length - 1) != null)
        bOut = true;

    return bOut;
}
...
```

Otherwise, Amir's answer would just work perfectly.

Comment: if you have multiple return path from your 'if's this definitely better, but for simple 'if' 'else' returning from that location is fine.